# Symfony 4: Attempted to call function from wrong namespace

Tags: symfony, namespaces, symfony4

I am new to symfony.

I'm trying to follow some tutorial but I'm stuck with the use of ORM

I generated an entity with the following command:

```
php bin/console make:entity
```

My entity has a field "name" and therefore a function setName ()

I generated a controller with the command:

```
php bin/console make:controller TestController
```

In this controller I try to register a new entry but I have this error that appears:

> Attempted to call function "setName" from namespace "App \ Controller".

What I'm doing wrong ?

TestController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use App\Entity\Team;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/test", name="test")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $team = new Team();
        $team.setName("Marvels 6");

        $entityManager->persist($team);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->json([
            'message' => 'Welcome to your new controller!',
            'path' => 'src/Controller/TestController.php',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Team.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TeamRepository")
 */
class Team
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Poule", inversedBy="teams")
     */
    private $poule;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPoule(): Poule
    {
        return $this->poule;
    }

    public function setPoule(Poule $poule): self
    {
        $this->poule = $poule;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ist that your copy&pasted code?

```
$team.setName("Marvels 6");
```

should probably be:

```
$team->setName("Marvels 6");
```

Comment: Oh, you're right.

I made too much javascript lately.

Thanks to you.